# Mac versus Windows: End of line and carriage return

Tags: windows, macos, scripting, newline, carriage-return

This a question about getting Macs and Windows PCs to play nicely with each other.

SCENARIO: I use a Mac. I have a bunch of data files that need some slicing and dicing to use with a visualization toolkit. The visualization software is for Windows only, which is no problem since I have a virtual Windows machine. `awk` was my tool of choice for this problem, and it generated the input files beautifully. Unfortunately, when I generate the input files for the visualization tool and send them over to the PC, there are no new lines; i.e., on the Mac I open (say) `output001.txt`:

```
header.info

# file automatically generated by awk

BEGIN File
...
<columns of data>
...
END File
```

Looks great, but then I open in on the PC and have:

```
header.info# file automatically generated by awkBEGIN File...<columns of data>...END File
```

I understand that Windows and Mac OS treat end of line characters differently. I've read that `\n` on a Mac stands for newline AND character return whereas Windows treats them separately, necessitating `\n\r`. But here, the problem is somewhat different. I never used a `\n` character generating the text file -- `awk` did all the newlines.
Is there a character that I can have `awk` put at the end of each line it writes so that Windows will understand where the newlines go?

Comment: "PCs" do not 'open' documents, some software that you got installed will do that. If you are using Windows and Notepad: Notepad is a brain dead plain text editor. Please use *anything* else for serious work: TextPad or Sublime Text. Both ought to be able to work seamlessly with other flavors of line endings.

Comment: Did I say PCs 'open' documents? I selected an automatically generated text file using a visualization toolkit. It complained about the very first line. So I then opened this (plain text) file in Notepad, for the sole purpose of looking inside. And what did I see? A bunch of data on a single line with no newlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, make the *"Output Record Separator"* a `Carriage Return` plus `Linefeed`. So instead of

```
seq 1 10 | awk '1' | cat -vet
1$
2$
3$
4$
5$
6$
7$
8$
9$
10$
```

use

```
seq 1 10 | awk '1' ORS='\r\n' | cat -vet
1^M$
2^M$
3^M$
4^M$
5^M$
6^M$
7^M$
8^M$
9^M$
10^M$
```

**Notes:**

`seq 1 10` just generates the numbers from 1 to 10.

`1` amounts to `true` in `awk` which means it should just do its default thing - which means to just print the current line.

I just use `cat -vet` to show the Carriage Returns, i.e `^M`.